# An automatic 'site duplicating and numbering' script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites, sites

I'm quite new to Google Apps Script and I was wondering if it is possible to create a script which duplicates a template site and 'numbers' the new one's Title, Name, etc..

Here's what I'd want it to do:

1. copy template site called "site0000"
2. automatically create sites called site0001, site0002, site0003, etc.
3. optionally customize each one of them

So far I came up with this very simple copying script that is giving me an error when debugging and creates a blank "site0001" site

```
function CopySite() {

var siteCopy = SitesApp.copySite("mydomain.com", "site0000", "site0000",
//I have no idea what to put here//)

var site = SitesApp.createSite("mydomain.com", "site0001", 
"site0001", "Site 0001")    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.copySite()` creates the new site. You don't need to use `.createSite()` afterwards. So, if you already have a 'site0000' at 'mydomain.com' and just want to copy it calling the new one 'site0001', try this

```
function copySite(){
var site = SitesApp.getSite('mydomain.com', 'site0000'); //find the site to copy
var newSite = SitesApp.copySite('mydomain.com', 'site0001', 'Site 0001', 'Site description', site); //create the new site
}
```

Then you can do what you like with `newSite`.

You'll probably want to use variables for the new sites' names, etc. if you are going to be creating multiple of them.

Comment: Very very helpful and kind. Thank you so much.

Comment: hey dmusgrave. In the last couple of days I tried to figure out a way to use variables on the new sites' suggestion but I couldn't do it. I'd appreciate a lot if you could clarify what you meant by that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just meant that rather than calling every new site 'site0001', you might want to use a variable so each new site can have a unique name. Even just something simple that counts the number of sites you already have, then adds 1 for the name of the new site.